# Install GCC in Git for Windows bash environment

Tags: windows-7, mingw, git-bash, msys

I have Git for Windows installed on a Windows 7 machine (no, sadly I can't switch to W10 on this particular machine). This comes with a bash environment that uses MinGW-64 but only includes some binaries. I'd like to add more, such as GCC.

It seems like there should be someway of adding to the MinGW-64 binaries within the git bash instead of adding a whole other MSYS2/MinGW-64 install. However I'm not exactly clear on what is the best way to go about enabling this. I have tried installing [win-builds](http://win-builds.org/doku.php/start) in the bash install `usr/` directory (seemed like the place all the other binaries were). It seems to run OK but it doesn't seem to add anything AFAICT, no executables, no folders, nada... except if I try to run the install again it complains that there are already files there... though they patently aren't.

Thus my question is this: can I use win-builds or some other binary to achieve my aim and if so, how?

Note: There are several questions about this around the net and SE, but most are quite old and so no longer relevant AFAICT due to changes in MSYS2, MinGW and Git for Windows.

[image: screenshot showing win-builds complaining that non-existant folders exist]

Comment: Ah. I see the following is likely relevant and probably means I should just go install MSYS separately. I'll leave this question open for a while in case someone has alternatives. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32712133/1292918

Comment: What’s wrong with replacing Git for Windows entirely?

Comment: @DanielB I hadn't considered that TBH. Though I do like to have the GUI there in case something goes drastically wrong. On such occasions I don't like to have to spend time researching arcane command options to get output that is easily visually parsable.

Comment: You can always use a different GUI like SourceTree oder Git Extensions. Git also ships with `gitk`, but I don’t know whether that would be available with MSYS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW I just uninstalled Git for Windows and instead installed both GCC and git within MSYS2, as @DanielB commented.

Answer (score 10):

### USE MINGW-W64

1. Install [**mingw-w64**](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds) (*Follow the "Sourceforge" link*) and install it to the default **`Program Files`** based path.
2. Select the latest *"version"* (for GCC), change *"architecture"* from `i686` (32-bit) to `x86_64` (64-bit), and change *"threads"* to `win32`.
3. Add the `bin` folder to the beginning of your Git BASH (MINGW64) path:

   ```
    $ export PATH="c:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-win32-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin:$PATH"
   ```

   You'll, of course, need to adjust the above path to match the version of your of your particular install:

   ```
    $ export PATH="c:/Program Files/mingw-w64/<YOUR_ARCH_VERSION_REVISION_FOLDER>/mingw64/bin:$PATH"
   ```

#### Alternatively

You may be able to just install it directly into the same folder as **Git**:
`C:\Program Files\Git`.

But I haven't tried this alternative approach and I wouldn't recommend it because it is likely to cause issues when updating and may confuse uninstallers, leaving remnants. (*if the two installations don't interfere to begin with*)

[ ***Edit***:  **GNU Make** is installed as `mingw32-make.exe`.  You can make a copy of it, somewhere in your `$PATH` which you have permission to, and rename it to `make`.  Git Bash seems to respect that it's executable, even without an extension, which is handy if you don't want it picked up outside of the MinGW environment (even though it may be in your PATH). ]

Answer (score 1):

You have to share Windows' PATH (and probably other) environment variables with MinGW. For MSYS2 you can share them by adding this to your Windows' env. variables:

`MSYS2_PATH_TYPE=inherit`